# OWASP ZAP: Active scanning manual explored Actions

Tags: owasp, zap

I started, with an automatic scan of my site under test.
Then I have explored it manually to test actions, not found by the automatic scan.
These Actions are visible in the History Tab.

I stored the session.

How can I re-run those manually added actions? I didn't find them as executed, when running an active scan again.

Answer (score 1):

You can explore your app in a variety of ways using ZAP:

- Manual exploring - very effective but no good for automation
- Traditional Spider - fast but doesnt handle modernapp which use JS
- Ajax Spider - slower but handles modern apps
- Proxying unit tests - good it you have them
- Importing definitions such as OpenAPI, SOAP, GraphQL
- Proxying a program/script which makes those requests for you

For more details see the vidoes taged 'explore' on https://www.zaproxy.org/videos-list/

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to the party, but if still someone needs this, here is what you can do.

1. Explore all the sites manually which ZAP couldn't detect using spider
2. Save a session by clicking on "Snapshot session as"
3. Reopen same session and start scanning next time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).